# Insert to certain row in sqlflite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, flutter, mobile

I am attempting to make a database that stores user information on the device. I am using flutter combined with sqlflite. I want to always store the data of the current user in row one of the SQL database. Is there anyway to do that with the .insert method?

```
  int id = await db.insert(
          'user',
          user.toMap(),
          conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
        );
```

This is the code I am using for inserting, but when the user changes the screen name or email, it will put the user now into the second row.

Comment: Tables are conceptually unordered data. There is no "row one". If you want a select to return rows in a certain order you need an `ORDER BY`,

Comment: After quite a bit of troubleshooting I discovered my code was actually correct, however, the return type is a List<User>. I had to simply cast to that and take the first index. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long period of research, I came to discover that the issue was not in my SQL code, it was instead in my use of the code. The object was returning a list of all objects and I was thinking it was returning one object.